# How to evaluate PHP session for redirecting user to admin panel?

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

I want to set session for my `panel.php` file in my `check.php` file. I define `$_SESSION['admin']= 1` and then I evaluate admin session in my `panel.php` file But I don't know why my panel page redirects to `index.php` (login form).

I bring all the codes below:

***check.php:***

```
<?php
include_once ("function.php");
$username = $_POST['tfuser'] ;
$password = $_POST['tfpass'] ;

if (isset($username) && isset($password)){
  $link = mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die ('error in connecting to db');
  mysql_select_db('login',$link) or die ('error select db');

  $sql = "select * from administration 
  where username='$username' and password='$password'";

  $result = mysql_query($sql,$link);

  if (mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    //login to panel 
    redirect("panel.php");
    $_SESSION['admin']= 1 ;
  } else {
    //back to login page
    redirect("index.php?error");
  }
} else {
  //back to login page
  redirect("index.php");
}

?>
```

***panel.php:***

```
<?php
include_once ("function.php");
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['admin'])==1){
  session_destroy();
  redirect("index.php");
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>admin panel</title>
</head>

<body>
welcome to admin panel
</body>
</html>
```

How can I solve this redirect?

Comment: And your question is? (Also if you more properly format your code, would be helpful)

Comment: @hakre may i ask ... is it good to start session after including any file like the op does in panel.php since i think thing like this will generate session warning/error

Comment: @NullPointer: Yes that can be an issue. However it's not yet clear to me what the actual question/problem is. Is there any warning or error message for example? Maybe putting `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(~0);` on top of the script will reveal more information about such and other related problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to redirect function is before setting $_SESSION['admin']

Comment: You redirect from this page before setting variable, that's why $_SESSION['admin'] is still empty. 
I guess your redirect function looks like:
function redirect($url) {
    header("Location: $url");
    exit;
}

After calling this function further execution will break and client will be redirected to the url.

Comment: Simply reverse these two lines

Comment: I see this solution below (ommiting PDO)

Answer (score 0):

try checking if something is being stored in $result or not.

Comment: yeah I'm sure about this matter,arise from this fact something is wrong in my session validation because when i removed **!** from my validate here: if (!isset($_SESSION['admin'])==1) ,my script work correctly

Comment: okay, also one thing i noticed you have not called session_start() in check.php file.

Comment: @Delphinium This is a very terse answer. Perhaps it would have been better as a comment on the original question?

Comment: @DuncanJones i agree, but i am a little new to stackoverflow and don't know how to really do that! So a little apology there.

Comment: @Delphinium Sorry, I suspect you are unable to do that because of your current low reputation. Apologies for moaning! :-)

Answer (score 0):

As your writing new code you should be avoiding the mysql_* functions, here is your code fixed & ported to PDO perhaps its of some interest.

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once ("function.php");

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    if (isset($_POST['tfpass']) && isset($_POST['tfuser'])){
        // PDO CONNECT
        try {
            $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=login", 'root', 'pass');
            $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        }catch (Exception $e){
            die('mySQL server error: '.$e->getMessage());
        }

        $sql = "SELECT 1
                FROM administration
                WHERE username=:user AND password=:pass";

        //Prepare the above query
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        //bind the placeholders to the values
        $stmt->bindParam(':user', $_POST['tfuser']);
        $stmt->bindParam(':pass', $_POST['tfpass']);
        //Execute
        $stmt->execute();
        //Fetch Result
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if (!empty($result)){
            //login to panel
            $_SESSION['admin']= 1 ;
            redirect("panel.php");
        } else {
            //back to login page
            redirect("index.php?error");
        }
    } else {
        //back to login page
        redirect("index.php");
    }
}else{
    //back to login page, script not accessed via POST
    redirect("index.php");
}
?>
```